# Laravel Dropdownlist : Data couldn't load form the database to view page

Tags: php, laravel, drop-down-menu, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I want to show Class Name from the database name:Class. But while load the create page it's showing the following Error.

> FatalErrorException in courseController.php line 23: syntax error,
>   unexpected 'Class' (T_CLASS)

here is my Course Controller where I want to show the class data in View Page:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Course;
use Redirect;

class courseController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $alldata=Course::all();
        return  view('course.index',compact('alldata'));
    }


    public function create()
    {
        $input = Class::lists('name', 'id');
        return view('course.create',compact('input'));
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        Course::create($input);
        //return $input;  { for seeing the output in browser}
        return redirect('course');
    }   
}
```

Here is my Class model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Class extends Model
{
    protected $table="classes";
    protected $primaryKey="id";
    protected $fillable=['name'];
}
```

Here is the course Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Course extends Model
{
    protected $table="courses";
    protected $primaryKey="course_id";
    protected $fillable=['course_code','course_title','course_credit'];
}
```

And Here is the view page where I want to load the data

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <title> Create Course </title>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container" >
            <h3> Create course </h3>
        {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'course.store','class'=>'form-horizontal'))  !!}
        {!! Form::token(); !!}
            <?php echo csrf_field(); ?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Course Code</label>
                <input type="text" name="course_code" class="form-control"  placeholder="Code">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Course Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="course_title" class="form-control"  placeholder="Title">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Course Credit</label>
                <input type="text" name="course_credit" class="form-control"  placeholder="Credit">
            </div>


    {!! Form::select('id', $input) !!}                


  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if my answer was helpful, please upvote it and choose it as best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to make it work and also rename you `Class` to something like `TheClass`:

```
use App\TheClass;
```

You need this to actually use `TheClass`. Also, `class` is reserverd word in PHP:
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

Comment: Well, you should use `use App\Class;` anyway if you want to use it. Also, try to rename your Class to `TheClass` and please tell me about the result.

Comment: yes, I have changed Class to TheClass and still getting the same error.

Comment: DId you insert `use` construction? Did you change `Class` to `TheClass` **everywhere** in the script and also in `Class` itself? Please double check everything, because it really should work now.

Answer (score 0):

replace `Class` with your class name `Course` :

```
$input = Class::lists('name', 'id');
```

to be:

```
$input = Course::lists('name', 'id');
```

Comment: you cannot give the class name **Class**

Comment: I don't understanding what you are saying bro ..Here this Class is a Model. why are referring to class Name?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

$input = \App\Class::lists('name', 'id');

And let see what happens. I guess the name Class can be rename to something else to avoid any confusion.